# Next big global technological breakthrough with a next-gen DevOps toolchain backbone - in an imaginary world, who would be able to support that?

Tags: internal-consistency

While software as it was "eating the world" and penetrating industries in first decades of the 21st century, it became an important driver of technological progress.

Then, *DevOps* has been a set of methods and practices to boost team productivity, speed of delivery and product quality.

DevOps being first of all a team culture and a mindset, on physical side needed a set of well interoperable tools, and also a universal backbone software to plug them in.

In a diverse and fragmented market, two market dominating products emerged; one bought by a proprietary company for an astronomic value as it attracted most developers globally, and one available as open source, and developed together with the community by a smaller private company.

Many expected the open source product to thrive, but even DevOps applied to a DevOps product faces huge complexity of issue backlog with dozens of thousands items and threaded conversations.

As of 2021, innovative approaches were introduced like machine learning driven tagging of new assets.

But it was only the beginning. In late 2021, a group of industrial leaders decided to create a breakthrough initiative, as they expected that faster development of such a tool would greatly increase furthrer worlwide speedup.

As of mid 2040s, things indeed changed a lot.

...
Question: given the imaginary world is an exact copy of ours, which individuals, either existing initiatives, seem mostly likely to assume the above and step forward, as of early 2021? Not opinion, but provable.

Comment: I am not sure I get what you are asking. Moreover, how do you expect us to produce something provable about your world?

Comment: @L.Dutch-ReinstateMonica - thx - it's an exact copy of ours, as of now. Beyond that, what's exactly not clear?

Comment: It's not clear what is the worldbuilding problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: Following the site info: "Specific issues with worldbuilding; Real problems or questions that you’ve encountered". My issue is that if the imaginary world is exact copy of ours, where the described event is not happening, there must be some sort of turning point; so I thought it might be an initiative similar to "Starshot breakthrough initiative". But maybe it would something else different to relatively slow evolutionary process and I have no idea.

Comment: I honestly have trouble following what has or hasn't happened in the imaginary world. Who is assuming what. What and how needs to be proven.

Comment: How does one quantify "most likely to produce a phenomenal innovation?" There has never been a metric for this; thus, there is no "provable" way (barring someone inventing time travel to go look) to answer this question. All answers will be opinion-based.

Comment: "seem mostly likely ... Not opinion, but provable." How exactly does one prove who is most likely to be able to accomplish a future advancement which itself is just a vague 'things get better' kind of idea? I could name off a dozen ideas for who, with decent reasons, but nothing is provable about predicting the future. So what makes up a reasonable answer here?

Answer (score 2):

#### Frame challenge - DevOps breakthrough will be of minimal benefit as it will hit other limiting factors

As a software engineer whose often limited by my DevOps toolchain; I wish for this with all my heart. It would be so nice to have those toolchains issue free.

However, with a bit of reflection, (and in spite of my regular requests to management arguing the contrary) development is not limited by the DevOps systems, nor is it limited by compilation speed, or my internet connection, or anything else technical.

Development speed is limited by how fast I can turn concepts in my head into functional lines of code that do what I want.  Even a Neural implant that pulls thoughts from my head and turns them into code will still have the same bottleneck.

Your not going to get a "DevOps singularity" that'll speed up development like this. Until we have epic AI in some form that can convert high level thoughts into bug-free code, or true AI that can just write its own code (neither of which would be described as a DevOps breakthrough), development will remain bound by the transform of thought-to-code in an engineers head.

Comment: By the way: https://medicalxpress.com/news/2020-06-language-brain-scans-reveal-coding.html

Comment: Maybe it's not effectively writing code but offloading tedious work to extents as far as a narrow AI can go by augmenting and replacing humans where possible to see it as a virtual ("stupid") manpower?